# Help with alignat environment

Tags: align

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{3}
    &\text{Case 1: } s^*\leq a&\quad &\hphantom{\leq} 2\beta \leq& 2a\alpha-4\lambda-\tau &\Rightarrow s^* = \frac{2\beta+4\lambda+\tau}{2\alpha}\\
    &\text{Case 2: } a < s^* \leq b&\quad 2a\alpha-4\lambda+\tau &\leq 2\beta \leq& 2b\alpha-4\lambda+\tau &\Rightarrow s^*=\frac{2\beta+4\lambda-\tau}{2\alpha}\\
    &\text{Case 3: } b < s^* \leq c&\quad 2b\alpha-2\lambda+\tau &\leq 2\beta \leq& 2c\alpha-2\lambda+\tau &\Rightarrow s^* = \frac{2\beta+2\lambda-\tau}{2\alpha}\\
    &\text{Case 4: } c < s^* \leq d&\quad 2c\alpha+\tau &\leq 2\beta \leq& 2d\alpha+\tau &\Rightarrow s^* = \frac{2\beta-\tau}{2\alpha}\\
    &\text{Case 5: } d < s^* \leq e&\quad 2d\alpha+2\lambda+\tau &\leq 2\beta \leq& 2e\alpha+2\lambda+\tau & \Rightarrow s^* = \frac{2\beta-2\lambda-\tau}{2\alpha}\\
    &\text{Case 6: } e < s^*&\quad 2e\alpha+4\lambda+\tau &\leq 2\beta \hphantom{\leq}& &\Rightarrow s^* = \frac{2\beta-4\lambda-\tau}{2\alpha}
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

The above code results in the PDF:

[image: PDF output]

Everything is right except the 4th line. Why is the `2d\alpha+\tau` aligning right? How can I get it to align immediately with `\leq`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a better alignment, you can use the following (and forget about the `\hphantom`s):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{9}
  & \text{Case 1: }&      & s^* &\leq a &                          &         &&        2\beta & \leq  {}&& 2a\alpha - 4\lambda &{}- \tau &&{} \Rightarrow {}& s^* &{}={}& \frac{2\beta + 4\lambda + \tau}{2\alpha}\\
  & \text{Case 2: }& a <{}& s^* &\leq b &\quad 2a\alpha - 4\lambda &{}+ \tau &&{} \leq 2\beta & \leq  {}&& 2b\alpha - 4\lambda &{}+ \tau &&{} \Rightarrow {}& s^* &{}={}& \frac{2\beta + 4\lambda - \tau}{2\alpha}\\
  & \text{Case 3: }& b <{}& s^* &\leq c &\quad 2b\alpha - 2\lambda &{}+ \tau &&{} \leq 2\beta & \leq  {}&& 2c\alpha - 2\lambda &{}+ \tau &&{} \Rightarrow {}& s^* &{}={}& \frac{2\beta + 2\lambda - \tau}{2\alpha}\\
  & \text{Case 4: }& c <{}& s^* &\leq d &\quad 2c\alpha            &{}+ \tau &&{} \leq 2\beta & \leq  {}&& 2d\alpha            &{}+ \tau &&{} \Rightarrow {}& s^* &{}={}& \frac{2\beta            - \tau}{2\alpha}\\
  & \text{Case 5: }& d <{}& s^* &\leq e &\quad 2d\alpha + 2\lambda &{}+ \tau &&{} \leq 2\beta & \leq  {}&& 2e\alpha + 2\lambda &{}+ \tau &&{} \Rightarrow {}& s^* &{}={}& \frac{2\beta - 2\lambda - \tau}{2\alpha}\\
  & \text{Case 6: }& e <{}& s^* &       &\quad 2e\alpha + 4\lambda &{}+ \tau &&{} \leq 2\beta &         &&                     &         &&   \Rightarrow {}& s^* &{}={}& \frac{2\beta - 4\lambda - \tau}{2\alpha}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: you've got the spacing around the operators and relations correct -- congrats.  but you don't actually need `{}` before an operator or relation that immediately follows `&` (it doesn't hurt, though).  what you *do* need (and you've got it right) is `{}` *after* an operator or relation that precedes an `&`.  this does seem to confuse people ...

Comment: @barbarabeeton Can I make you update my answer with the improved code? If I try and remove any of the `{}` the spacing is no longer correct.

Comment: okay, i've tested this, and you're quite right -- if the `{}` before the `+` signs are removed, the spacing closes up.  i don't think this should happen, but there must be a reason.  i'll look into it and report back.  (but maybe not today.)

Comment: please send me your e-mail address (you can use the address on my profile if you don't know my "real" one).  i have a brief test that's too complicated for either a comment or chat; it needs more study, but it shows something unexpected that i think will interest you.  however, be assured that the answer you have here is solid, and i haven't come up with anything better.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I have send an email to tech-support@ams.org.

Comment: Wow! This is more than I'd asked for. Thanks! I'm not sure if this is what you are discussing above, but I don't understand what purpose the {} serve. Also, could you explain when to use & and when to use &&?

Comment: The `{}`s are there to get the correct spacing around the operators (`+`, `-` and so on) and relations (`=` and so on). For the `alignat` usage, see, e.g., section 25.2 in [`Math mode`](http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) by Herbert Voß or the [`amsmath manual`](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf). (For n alignment points, 2n-1 `&`s are needed.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Have you found the reason for the unexpected behaviour, Barbara?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg -- not yet; more complete explanation offline.

Answer (score 1):

You can rearrange `&` to find better alignment, bu instead, recall that `-` sign are surrounded by two medium spaces (TeXbook, page 167). So if we write:

```
&\text{Case 4: } c < s^* \leq d&\quad 2c\alpha\phantom{\:-\:2\lambda}+\tau &\leq 2\beta \leq& 2d\alpha\phantom{\:-\:2\lambda}+\tau &\Rightarrow s^* = \frac{2\beta-\tau}{2\alpha}
```

we will get

[image]

Comment: The alignment at the third `\geq` is wrong.

Comment: There are also spacing problems. I cannot recommend this usage.