# Unmatching symbols with the alignat environment

Tags: alignat

I have the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
&|a-b| & < c\\
-c & < a-b & < c
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

which produces this:

[image]

I tried the align environment at first, but it produced large whitespaces and upon a quick search I found to use the alignat environment instead. However, here the equations don't match up. How could it be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using TABstacks, is something like this what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine} 
\TABstackMath
\setstacktabulargap{0pt}
\TABbinary
\begin{document}
\[
\tabularCenterstack{rcl}{
&\vert a-b\vert & < c\\
-c  <& a-b & < c
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

In this particular case, but not in general, a `\tabbedCenterstack` could also be used to achieve the same result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine} 
\TABstackMath
\TABbinary
\begin{document}
\[
\tabbedCenterstack{
&\vert a-b\vert & < c\\
-c  <& a-b & < c
}
\]
\end{document}
```

---

The OP asks if the `amsmath` environments can be used exclusively.  Here is something, but it uses a shoehorn to make it fit unnaturally

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
&|&a-b&| & {}< c\\
-c  <& &a-b& & {}< c
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That would work indeed, but is there a way to do it using only the align/alignat (or similar) environments?

Comment: @user154989 See the suffix to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially you want the width of `|a-b|` to match that of `a-b`. This is achievable via [`eqparbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox)'s `\eqmakebox[<tag>][<align>]{<stuff>}`, setting `<stuff>` with the same `<tag>` using the maximum width across all `<tag>`s. The default `<align>`ment is `c`entred:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,eqparbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
       \eqmakebox[abs]{$\lvert a - b \rvert$} & < c \\
  -c <        \eqmakebox[abs]{$a - b$}        & < c
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

`alignat` processes elements in groups of two: `l&r & l&r` and doesn't leave any space between the groups. what you need to do to fix this, since you have no left-hand side to the second "group", is to double the second `&`.  you also need to add an empty group after the double `&&` since at the beginning of the first element of a group there is no automatic recognition of an operator or relation, hence the spacing will not be correct.

i also didn't understand why `align` wasn't suitable -- if only one alignment point is used, there shouldn't be any large spaces.  (the only reason i could think of was that you want a special alignment that isn't fully described.)  anyhow, i've included an example with `align` as well as with `alignat`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
   & |a-b| && {} < c\\
-c & < a-b && {} < c
\end{alignat*}

\begin{align*}
   |a-b| & < c\\
-c < a-b & < c
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

Answer (score 0):

There are similar questions to this which were already answered. See [for example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4273/align-two-inequalities). See [a more complex example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135817/help-with-alignat-environment) here. It looks like the solution with `\tabularCenterstack` is the most stable (but I did not test if the spacing is right around the `\le` sign.

But, in case you insist to use `alignat*`, remember that in `\begin{alignat*}{2}` you should have three `&` symbols in each line. In general, with `\begin{alignat*}{n}` you should have `2n-1` symbols `&`, so that you have `2n` spaces to type (including the beginning, the end and those in between the `&`s). The spaces correspond to the lefthandside and the righthandside of `n`equations respectively.

The problem is that `alignat*` is not meant to produce centered alignment in any of those columns (they alternate between right-aligned and left-aligned). In case all terms in a particular column are equal, usually you can fake centered alignment by correctly position the `&`s. Sometimes you need to use `{}` after the equality/inequality sign to have the correct spacing. On other cases, you may try to use some tricks, like the `\eqmakebox` when both terms have the same size, but the solution will not scale well unless you use some trick of Wener.